# How to apply app restriction on play store for android lollipop

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager

Like google chrome application, can we apply restriction to google play store app too? 
If anyone has tried it please reply with bundle structure for same.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: No one tried it yet???

Answer (score 4):

Please check below API to restrict chrome

```
final DevicePolicyManager manager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
final Bundle settings = new Bundle();
settings.putString("EditBookmarksEnabled", "false");
settings.putString("IncognitoModeAvailability", "1");
settings.putString("ManagedBookmarks",
                   "[{\"name\": \"Chromium\", \"url\": \"http://chromium.org\"}, " +
                   "{\"name\": \"Google\", \"url\": \"https://www.google.com\"}]");
settings.putString("DefaultSearchProviderEnabled", "true");
settings.putString("DefaultSearchProviderName", "\"LMGTFY\"");
settings.putString("DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL",
        "\"any URL\"");
settings.putString("URLBlacklist", "[\"facebook.com\", \"example.org\"]");
```

Now you can use

```
manager.setApplicationRestrictions(BasicDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(activity),
                                   packageName,
                                   settings);
```

to set restriction.

Comment: this is for chrome. I need same for play store app. :(

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Store app does not expose any app restriction to configure.

To get the list of app restrictions that an app exposes you can either

- read the app manifest's meta-data tag `android.content.APP_RESTRICTIONS` (more details in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager.html)),
- or call the [Products: getAppRestrictionsSchema](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/products/getAppRestrictionsSchema) method of the Play EMM API if you register as an EMM.